Show value and modify hover in sankey diagram (R plotly)
Example code to make a Sankey chart with plotly.
links <- data.frame(
  source=c("group_A","group_A", "group_B", "group_C", "group_C", "group_E"), 
  target=c("group_C","group_D", "group_E", "group_F", "group_G", "group_H"), 
  value=c(2,3, 2, 3, 1, 3)
)

nodes <- data.frame(
  name=c(as.character(links$source), 
         as.character(links$target)) %>% unique()
)

links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name)-1 
links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name)-1

plot_ly(
  type = "sankey",
  orientation = "h",
  textfont = list(size=11),
  node = list(
    label = nodes$name,
    pad = 15,
    thickness = 20),
  link = list(
    source = links$IDsource,
    target = links$IDtarget,
    value =  links$value))

Is it possible to add the 'value' on each link ? (See my photo 1 for example) :

I would also like to simplify the text on the hover. Indeed, I want to delete the "source" and "target" information and simply add this text :value : [links$value]
I have tried using hovertemplate  but apparently it is no longer a valid attributes. Here's the expected output :

Thank you in advance.

In a Sankey within Plotly, you have two places to set a hovertemplate or hoverinfo: the nodes and the links.
If you wanted only the nodes to show in the hover, then you need to set the links' hover to none and the nodes' hover to the format you want: link = list(hovertemplate ... and node = list(hoverinfo = "none"....
If you want to remove the source and target labels, you set the color to transparent in textfot = list(color = "transparent"....
If you want to add values to the plot, you'll have to use the plot domain (where both x and y are valued between 0 and 1) and use annotations to create a label for each node.
Here's an example of what this might look like.
plot_ly(
  type = "sankey",
  orientation = "h",
  textfont = list(color = "transparent"), # <---- I'm new
  node = list(
    hoverinfo = "none",                   # <---- I'm new
    label = nodes$name,
    pad = 15,
    thickness = 20),
  link = list(
    hovertemplate = "value: %{value}<extra></extra>", # <---- I'm new
    source = links$IDsource,
    target = links$IDtarget,
    value =  links$value)) %>% 
  layout(annotations = lapply(1:nrow(links), function(j) { # <---- I'm new
    list(x = c(.25, .5, .25, .75, .75, .75)[j],  # arbitrary values to align with plot
         y = c(2/3, .95, .15, 2/3, .45, .15)[j], 
         text = links$value[j],                  # show values
         xref = "paper",                         # use the plot domain
         yref = "paper",
         showarrow = F)                          # no arrows necessary
  })
  )




If you have any questions or problems with this, let me know.
